# Are there any ways to trap Ctrl-V event in Windows C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, window

I've only found `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`,but it could only trap Ctrl-C and other stuff,I've searched Google and found no documentation about Ctrl-V.

Comment: Definitely possible.  I know it at the hwnd level (replacing it's wndproc let's you intercept anything) and you can get the console hwnd so...

Comment: Disable "Ctrl key shortcuts" in the menu? MS probably forgot to publish (or write) an API do do that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291284/handle-ctrlc-on-win32 Maybe This? You might be able to change it to work for `CTRL_V_EVENT`..

Comment: @the_electro_bros nagtive, there is no macro for CTRL_V_EVENT

Comment: Oh. Surprising, I would have expected them to have added that...